# UITableView not updating after NSArray changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have async request to HTTP, i want to read JSON and fill my viewtable.

I get data with request, i make NSArray, but i can pass it inside my functions, tableView numberOfRowsInSection return only 1, please help.

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class ThirdView : UITableViewController {

var jsonz:NSArray = ["Ray Wenderlich"];
let url = NSURL(string: "http://iweddings.ru/xmlrestaurant.json");

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray
        println(json)
// here i see in xCode output
//        price = 4500;
//        rating = 45;
//        slogan = "\U041d\U0435\U043b\U0435\U0433\U0430\U043b\U044c\U043d\U043e";
//        status = 1;
//        type = 1;
// etc....


            self.jsonz = json;
    }

    task.resume()


}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    println(self.jsonz.count);
    return self.jsonz.count;
// here i see always "1" ???? why?
}
```

NSArray **jsonz** does not change.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `reloadData()` method after json data is downloaded:

```
class ThirdView: UITableViewController {
    var jsonz: NSArray = ["Ray Wenderlich"]
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://iweddings.ru/xmlrestaurant.json")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as! NSArray
            println(json)

            self.jsonz = json;
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        task.resume()
    }


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        println(self.jsonz.count);
        return self.jsonz.count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but it is ~40 sec. 40 seconds i see only one cell and after this all 6 cells are loading. Did you know why? When i use non async request, it is ~4 sec. for all loading.

Comment: It looks like you are updating the tableView on a background thread. Move the reloadData() onto the main thread.

Comment: I moved, still 40 seconds :(

Comment: how did you move it? update  your code with your changes,